# Difference among Dimension, Dimension attribute and Facts

Tags: database, data-warehouse

So from what I've understand the best example of differences in (Dimension, Dimension Attribute, and Fact) would be something like this:

**Dimensions** - PRODUCT, ACCOUNT, CUSTOMER

**Dimension attribute** - ProductName, ProductNumber, CustomerName, CustomerNumber

**Facts** - usually measures. Dollar, Unit, Height

This is my attempt so it may be wrong. I want to hear your solutions?

Comment: What differences are you talking about? Please [edit] your question and add more details like your data model.

Answer (score 4):

A dimension is a collection of "reference information" about a measurable event. The Measurable event is a Fact.

So, if you have data say for example - Retail transactions, you would measure - transaction cost. So, your fact will have sales amount. Now, sales amount in itself does not make sense. You would need information like -

1. When was the sale done - Date dimension
2. Who made the transaction - Customer dimension
3. Which store was it made from - Store Dimension
4. What was brought - Product dimension

and so on. What information you want capture for each dimension is called the attributes. For Ex: A Customer dimension might have these attributes -

Customer Number
Customer Name
Customer Address
Customer Zip Code
Date Of birth
... and so on.

Comment: Can my fact also have sales date? The date when that sale happened. Or that would be a dimension

Comment: @Dino Yes, it could. A fact table has columns that refer to relevant dimensions—the numbered list in the answer. They give the context for the measures. Whether it should have a sales date depends on, for one, the grain of the fact table. Is it daily, monthly, quarterly, or …?

Answer (score 3):

**Dimensions:**  are qualitative data. These are objects of the subjects.

**Dimension attributes :** These are columns of dimension table.

**Facts** : are the quantitative data. The data which can be summed up , averaged or manipulated. If manipulation is done in the data then it would be to provide business insights. **Manipulated data eg :** time dimension  can't be measured but hours calculated using time is a measurable fact.

**Example :** Consider e commerce company table(amazon) which is **Subject**

1. **Dimensions:**

   Product , date , customer , vendor , location(** these all are Objects of subjects**)
2. **Dimension attributes:**

   ```
    PRODUCT - (Product_id , Product_name , Product_class)
    DATE - (Order_date , Shipment_Date , Delivery_date)
    CUSTOMER - (Cust_id , Cust_name)
    LOCATION -(State , city , town , zip_code)
   ```
3. **Facts:**

   ```
    PRODUCT - Total number of products sold 
    DATE -  Total number of products sold in last one month/ last one year / last one quater
    CUSTOMER - Total amount paid by customer
    LOCATION - Total sales done per region , per state , per city
             - Total traffic(customer visited) in stores per region
   ```